# Django server returning a 404 out of nowhere

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to Django and coding to be honest!

I'm facing a problem that appeared out of nowhere when I was finishing a website I can't seem to find anything here that helps with my case.

The problem goes with when I try to run the server with `python manage.py runserver` it gives me this error :

```
 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 27, 2022 - 17:30:51
Django version 4.0.6, using settings 'sitewilza.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[27/Jul/2022 17:30:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2573
Not Found: /
[27/Jul/2022 17:30:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2573
```

and the server returns this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in sitewilza.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
sobremim [name='sobre']
formacao [name='formacao']
contato [name='contato']
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

the problem is I did not change anything in both my urls.py, here they are :

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('website.urls')),
]
```

&

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 


urlpatterns = [
    path('sobremim', views.sobremim, name='sobre'),
    path('formacao', views.formacao, name='formacao'),
    path('contato', views.contato, name='contato'),
]
```

note that i was editing my contato.html file using a anchor to set up a Instagram forward link.

I don't know if my questing is well presented or not, but I hope you guys can understand and thank you in advance for your time in helping me.

Comment: I found that if I use http://127.0.0.1:8000/sobremim instead of just http://127.0.0.1:8000/ it works, but how can I make it always go to the "sobremim" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So see, you have to understand django flow cycle and then you will be able to develop your website properly.

Here is what you doing in your `urls.py` when you are requesting your django local server is you are calling `urls.py` of `website` app so but you are not telling django what to do exactly whem `/` is called.

This will fix your problem:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.sobremim, name='sobre'),
    path('formacao', views.formacao, name='formacao'),
    path('contato', views.contato, name='contato'),
]
```

Update your `urls.py` file of website app and you will get your response.

Comment: thanks, I actually figured out by myself, but I think other people might be interested in this!